# jquery-easyui datagrid editor=numberspinner

Tags: jquery-easyui

[sample](http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/datagrid/datagrid23.php)

How to set **"Max"** variable value for **numberspinner**, dependent **rowValue** (**listprice** or **unitcost**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look easyui documantation [here](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/index.php) open **numberspinner** from left pane. And he says on first sentence :

> Extend from $.fn.spinner.defaults and $.fn.numberbox.defaults.
>   Override defaults with $.fn.numberspinner.defaults.

So you should open **spinner** from left pane and it has **max, min** properties. You can use this properties for **numberspinner** too.